Can an else if statement be used to create a step-wise reveal of elements with JavaScript?
Edit: Thank you! This problem is resolved. This was my first StackExchange question and you've all been very kind in responding so quickly, insightfully and thoroughly.
I'm building a page that has an "add another task" button. Each time it's pressed, one hidden element is supposed to change CSS properties from "hidden" to "visible", adding one more row of inputs to the page. I've managed to get them all to reveal at once, but I'm trying to get the rows to show one at a time.
Here's what I've written so far. Else if statements made the most sense to me, based on the SE posts I read about them, but with the first press of the button, both hidden rows ("task2" and "task3") reveal simultaneously. Am I using the wrong kind of conditional statement? Or do the statements need to be inside their own functions within the showNextTask function? I'd appreciate any help!
function showNextTask() {
                let task2 = document.querySelector("#task-2-row");
                let task3 = document.querySelector("#task-3-row");

                if ((task2.style.visibility === "hidden")) {
                    task2.style.visibility = "visible";
                    task2.style.maxHeight = "80px";
                } else if (
                    (task2.style.visibility === "visible") &&
                    (task3.style.visibility === "hidden")
                ) {
                    task3.style.visibility = "visible";
                    task3.style.maxHeight = "80px";
                }
            }

let nextInputTask = document.querySelector("#add-another-task-button");
nextInputTask.addEventListener("click", showNextTask);

As requested below, here is the HTML of Task 2 (Task 3 is identical):
<div id="task-2-row">
                    <form id="add-task-2">
                        <span class="add-task-2-description">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Task 2"
                                autocomplete="off"
                                id="task-input-bar-2"
                                class="task-input-field"
                            />
                        </span>
                        <span class="add-task-2-time">
                            <input
                                type="time"
                                id="timer-field-2"
                                class="task2 timer-field"
                                name="appt"
                            />
                            <input
                                type="submit"
                                id="submit-task-2-button"
                                class="button add-timer-button"
                                value="Add Task"
                            />
                        </span>
                    </form>
                </div>

And the CSS:
    #task-2-row {
                visibility: hidden;
                max-height: 0;
            }


= is for assignment, === is for comparison

What do you plan to do when the user wants to add 10 tasks, or 20?

Surely it makes more sense rather than showing hidden elements to inject a new element at the end each time there is a click?

"but with the first press of the button, both hidden rows ("task2" and "task3") reveal simultaneously" - don't see how that could actually be the case (even with the already mentioned error regarding comparison); an if and an else branch can't execute "simultaneously".

@Pointy yes, you're right! I've fixed that, thank you. I'll update the question.

@trincot I'm working on making the feature into something scalable! For now I'm just demonstrating how the button would function if a user pressed it once or twice, as an example.

@Paulie_D you're right, that does make more sense. I'm not skilled enough to do that yet, but I'll read up about it and try that instead for my next iteration.

Can you add the HTML you are using? And any CSS?

why don't you use  visibility hidden for both task at the if condition

You are using Assignment operator =  instead of equality operator == or ===
Instead I suggest you can try to make a more generic function to add N number of task with the button
Try
 <style>
    .task-row {
        visibility: hidden;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out, visibility 0.3s ease-out;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
<body>

<button id="add-another-task-button">Add Task</button>
<div id="task-container">
    <!-- Tasks will be created dynamically -->
</div>

<script>
    let taskCount = 0;

    function addNewTask() {
        taskCount++;
        const taskContainer = document.querySelector("#task-container");
        const newTask = document.createElement("div");
        newTask.id = `task-${taskCount}-row`;
        newTask.className = "task-row";
        newTask.innerHTML = `Task ${taskCount}: <input type="text">`;

        taskContainer.appendChild(newTask);

        // Make new task visible
        setTimeout(() => {
            newTask.style.visibility = "visible";
            newTask.style.maxHeight = "80px"; 
        }, 0);
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
        let nextInputTask = document.querySelector("#add-another-task-button");
        nextInputTask.addEventListener("click", addNewTask);
    });
</script>

This approach will help to create any number of task with 'Add Task' CTA.

Oh, I see! I think this is what Paulie_D suggested above: injecting a new element with each button click - and you've provided the whole format here. I'm accepting this as the best answer, and I think I'll build the feature with your recommended approach, so it's easier to scale up to more than 3 "New Task" elements (thank you @trincot for pointing that out!). Thank you, Ashish Yadav!

Just to pinpoint why your if..else doesn't work:
You're checking task2.style.visibility, but that style was never set. Instead you have a CSS class that applies to that element, but that is not the same thing. To know how all applicable CSS styles affect the visibility of task2 you could use getComputedStyle.  Then it will work.
Another remark: in the else case you already know that task2 is visible, so there is no need to explicitly check for that again.
So change this:
if ((task2.style.visibility === "hidden")) {
    task2.style.visibility = "visible";
    task2.style.maxHeight = "80px";
} else if (
    (task2.style.visibility === "visible") &&
    (task3.style.visibility === "hidden")
) {
    task3.style.visibility = "visible";
    task3.style.maxHeight = "80px";
}

to this:
if ((getComputedStyle(task2).visibility === "hidden")) {
    task2.style.visibility = "visible";
    task2.style.maxHeight = "80px";
} else if (getComputedStyle(task3).visibility === "hidden") {
    task3.style.visibility = "visible";
    task3.style.maxHeight = "80px";
}

But as noted, this is not really a scalable approach. Also, playing with maxHeight like that really shows you want to use the display property and not visibility. Note that display takes different values, so make sure to look it up.

Thank you for coming back to this! I'll keep getComputedStyle in my toolbox for later, and for now I've changed my code to something a little easier to scale in the future. As for the visibility vs display property, it's unfortunately a requirement of the project I'm working on, though I might come back and change it once it's been looked at. Many thanks again!
